# Display updates like Facebook, instagram and other social networking sites

Tags: jquery, html, mysql, ajax, jsp

I'm working on a project in which user can share images, like and comment on them and accordingly all the data will be saved in the database
I want to display username, image, no. Of likes, no. Of comments on homepage.
I've used the append tag of jQuery and put it in a jsp while loop to append listitems into an unordered list.
Thus I've succeeded in displaying different images for different listitems bit when I fetch no. Of likes and display it in a span tag in listitem based on its Id, that number gets added to th e span tag of all the listitems.

Can someone help me or suggest me a new way to display updates like Facebook and Instagram does when we open the homepage...and respond accordingly when I click username or like icon or comment icon.
This is the script part that does the whole fetching and displaying stuff.

```
    <script>
    var image_id,image_src,nameHead, noOfLikes, likeIcon;

    $(document).ready(function() {

        <%
        Statement st = db.con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("Select * from followings_table where user_id='"+Integer.parseInt(session.getAttribute("user_id").toString())+"'");
        Statement statement_gallery = db.con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        ResultSet resultSet_gallery = statement_gallery.executeQuery("Select * from image_table where category='usual pic' ORDER BY datetime DESC");
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        while(rs.next()) {
            list.add(rs.getInt("user_two"));
            System.out.println(rs.getInt("user_two"));
        }
        int flag = 0;
    while(resultSet_gallery.next()) {
            System.out.println("Second"+resultSet_gallery.getInt("user_id"));
        if(list.contains(resultSet_gallery.getInt("user_id"))){
            flag=1;
        %> 
                image_id="<%=resultSet_gallery.getInt("image_id")%>";
                image_src="data:image/jpg;base64,<%=resultSet_gallery.getString("image")%>";
                nameHead="<%=resultSet_gallery.getString("username")%>";
                $( "#updateCol" ).append('<div class="w3-container w3-card-2 w3-white w3-round w3-margin-left w3-margin-right w3-margin-bottom"><br><img src="" alt="Avatar" class="w3-left w3-circle w3-margin-right" style="width:60px"><span class="w3-right w3-opacity">1 min</span><h4 id="nameHead"></h4><br><img id="demo_img" src="" style="width:100%;"><hr class="w3-clear"><div class="w3-container w3-white"><div class="w3-padding-xlarge w3-left"><a><i class="material-icons color-tuna" style="cursor: pointer; pointer-events: none;" id="like" onclick="like()">favorite_border</i><span class="w3-badge bg-valencia" id="no_of_likes" onclick="getLikeList()">0</span></a></div><div class="w3-padding-xlarge w3-left"><a><i class="material-icons color-tuna"style="cursor: pointer; pointer-events: none;" id="comment" >comment</i></a><span class="w3-badge bg-valencia" id="no_of_comments" onclick="getCommentList()">0</span></div></div></div>'); 

            getDetails();
      <%   
        }}if(flag==0) {%>
        $( "#updateCol" ).append('<div class="w3-container w3-card-2 w3-white w3-round w3-margin-left w3-margin-right w3-margin-bottom"><br><h4>Follow some users to get started.</h4><br><h4>All the updates will then appear in this section</h4><br></div>');
        <%}

        %>

    });
    function getDetails() {
        $("#nameHead").text(nameHead);
        document.getElementById("demo_img").setAttribute("id", image_id);
        document.getElementById(image_id).setAttribute("src", image_src);
        liketoggle("likeNumber.jsp?imageId="+image_id, cfunction);
    }
    function cfunction(xhttp) {
        var res = xhttp.responseText;
        var arr = res.split(';');
        if(arr[0]=='0') {
            noOfLikes = 'arr[0]';
            likeIcon="favorite_border";
        }
        else {
            noOfLikes = 'arr[0]';
        }
        return true;
    }
    function liketoggle(url, cfunc) {
        var xhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhttp.readyState === 4 && xhttp.status === 200) {
                cfunc(xhttp);
            }else if(xhttp.status === 404) {
                alert("request not completed");
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xhttp.send();
    }

        </script>
<div class="w3-col m7" id="updateCol">


    <!-- End Middle Column -->
    </div>
```

Comment: Show us yout code. Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the total number of likes and share count of any web URL with a little bit of PHP and FQL (Facebook Query Language).

You don’t have to fiddle with the Facebook SDK or the API and this trick works for both Facebook pages as well as any external web page that has the like button or has been shared on Facebook.

```
function facebook_count($url){

  // Query in FQL
        $fql  = "SELECT like_count ";
        $fql .= " FROM link_stat WHERE url = '$url'";

        $fqlURL = "https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?format=json&query=" . urlencode($fql);

        // Facebook Response is in JSON
        $response = file_get_contents($fqlURL);
        return json_decode($response);

    }

    $fb = facebook_count('https://www.facebook.com/digital.inspiration');

    // facebook like count
    echo $fb[0]->like_count;
```

Comment: @AayushKumar your question is not clear as to what exactly you want.             Can someone help me or suggest me a new way to display updates like Facebook and Instagram does when we open the homepage---???????

Comment: I have saved user details, images, no. Of likes, comments in my database...I want to fetch the latest images posted by other users including the no. Of likes, comments on them, just like Instagram and Facebook does.